# How to set application context while creating a war file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, deployment, tomcat8

I have been working on a web application (Java+Spring+Maven+HTML+CSS+js+JSP) and now I am trying to deploy it to tomcat. (I use IntelliJ as IDE)

I have lots of **relative paths** in code such as,

`<script type="text/javascript" src="./static/external/jquery-2.1.0.js">`

**OR**

`$.ajax({
        dataType: "html",
        url : "/yarimelma/deleteConversation",`

All those paths **work fine** when I test it locally with tomcat. I set **"Application Context" as default "/"** so no problem.

Problems start when I deploy my WAR to the remote server into Tomcat. **WAR file name is yarimelma-1.0.0.war** so that it **creates a context under tomcat** which is **/yarimelma-1.0.0** and serves my application from that context. **(https://[mydomain]/yarimelma-1.0.0)**

What happens in that case,  **all those paths in my code is unreachable** since it tries to find js, for example, **under https://{mydomain}/static/js/jquery.js** but it is actually reachable under https://{mydomain}/yarimelam-1.0.0/static/js/jquery.js due to the context it has been deployed.
My ajax calls also does not work for that reason because client tried to perform ajax calls to https://[mydomain]/yarimelma/connect but it should actually go https://[mydomain]/yarimelma-1.0.0/yarimelma/connect

Ay idea about the solution?

1-Should I set my application context somewhere in my spring configuration or war export setting to **/yarimelma-1.0.0** ?
2-what is the solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have a project with a similar structure.

In my config file I have:

```
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

This Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory.

Now in my JSPs I'm using scriptlets to get the resources path like:

```
<link href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/css/error.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Using request.getContextPath() you can get the context of your app (in your case, the context of the app in the server when you are deploying it)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSTL core taglib for that and I believe this is the most common way.

Just include it in your jsp:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

And use it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/static/external/jquery-2.1.0.js"/>"></script>
```

It will automatically take care about your context path.

Another option is to manually append context path to your urls as @canillas suggested, but instead of using scriplets I would recommend to use `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`.

So your URL might look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/external/jquery-2.1.0.js">
```